# Why won't my jquery work

Tags: jquery

I have more code but this is the important bit. The rest of it is a JS function and styling.

```
        <button onClick="gB()" id="gb"> clickme</button>
        <script  src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('button').eq(0).trigger('click');
                };
```

Comment: You don't really need a document *ready* handler if your script comes after the elements in question.

Comment: Please add some more context.  How is it not working? Are there any relevant messages in the inspector console? Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your code?  Tell us what happened.

Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you question as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can't mix a `<script>` tag with `src` **and** inner script. Make two tags

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // your script
</script>
```

Also, check your console while developing. It will point out errors for you.

Answer (score 3):

Because you forgot about closing bracket `)` in last line.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

You have basic syntax error. Always check the console for any errors / exceptions. + Google some basic tutorials how to start with jQuery etc.